# Installing SimpleSamlPHP 1.19.4 in Virtual Machine

Tags: php, vagrant, homestead, simplesamlphp

This is my first time setting up SSO and any help would be appreciated. For the testing stage, I am running a local Homestead/Vagrant setup with Nginx. Example site mapped `project.test`.

I have used the installation for [simplesamlphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install#section_2)

1. I have downloaded latest version of simplesamlphp which is 1.19.4. I have unzipped the folder and saved it in path `/home/vagrant/code/project/simplesamlphp-1.19.4/`
2. In the simplesamlphp-1.19.4/config/config.php file I have set the

'baseurlpath' => 'http://project.test/simplesaml/'

3. I have reboot the virtual machine and tried to visit the above url. I get error 404 not found.
4. Next step would be to [add configuration as SP](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp). I followed the instructions given by this      url and added code in file `simplesamlphp-1.19.4/metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php`. The code I added is:

   $metadata['http://project.test'] =
   [
   'SingleSignOnService'  => 'http://project.test/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
   'SingleLogoutService'  => 'http://project.test/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
   //    'certificate'          => 'example.pem',
   ];

How can I now test the communication? Do I omit any other steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some details on how your web server is configured (Apache/Nginx) but here are a few things to try:

1. You mentioned you've added the code to ".../simplesamlphp-1.19.4"

> Try to browse to http://project.test/simplesamlphp-1.19.4/
>
> Try to browse to http://project.test/projects/simplesamlphp-1.19.4/

2. Ensure your Apache/Nginx config is pointed to the correct location. By default the Apache Server will point to `/var/www/html`

> You can update the location that the Apache Server is looking for files by updating the `httpd.conf` file.
>
> [Read more here](https://opensource.com/article/18/2/how-configure-apache-web-server)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Noah. I tried to add code of SimpleSampl in the correct directory where the site project.test is configured in the Homestead.yaml file. The path is : 
- map: project.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/project/public 
Then, Ι visited the url: **http://project.test/simplesamlphp-1.19.4/www/** and i was redirected to **http://project.test/simplesamlphp-1.19.4/www/module.php/core/frontpage_welcome.php** , where I got an error.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SimpleSAML\Error\CriticalConfigurationError: The configuration is invalid: Setting secure cookie on plain HTTP is not allowed. in /home/vagrant/code/project/public/simplesamlphp-1.19.4/lib/SimpleSAML/Session.php:306 Stack trace: #0 /home/vagrant/code/project/public/simplesamlphp-1.19.4/lib/SimpleSAML/Error/Error.php(191): SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest() #1 /home/vagrant/code/project/public/simplesamlphp-1.19.4/lib/SimpleSAML/Error/Error.php(229): SimpleSAML\Error\Error->saveError() #2 /home/vagrant/code/project/public/simplesamlphp-1.19.4/www/_include.php(21).

Comment: Can you please give me some advice how can I overcome this error?

Comment: The error is corrected by adding in config.php file : ' 'session.cookie.secure' => false,'

Comment: I'd recommend following the SimpleSAML to ensure all parameters are set as required.

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install

Be sure to make the response as the answer since it was solving your question.

Comment: Thank you for your willing to help. Keep in touch maybe for another question in the future.